# How to use SaveChanges() for each row

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have table that has just 3 rows now I want update these rows for now I don't know how to save this row

```
if (_Shifts != null)
{
    ContexManager contex = new ContexManager();
    Shift _sht;         
    _Shifts[0].MyStartTime = dtStart1.Value.TimeOfDay;
    _Shifts[0].MyEndTime = dtEnd1.Value.TimeOfDay;
    _Shifts[0].MyName = txtShift1.Text;
    contex.SaveChanges();
}
```

it not save changes now, how to do for save changes in database, it's for update row[0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a loop over the values and finally add to a collection and do the SaveChanges()

```
if (_Shifts != null)
{
ContexManager contex = new ContexManager();
Foreach( var shiftitem in _Shifts)
{
  shiftitem.MyStartTime = dtStart1.Value.TimeOfDay;
  shiftitem.MyEndTime = dtEnd1.Value.TimeOfDay;
  shiftitem.MyName = txtShift1.Text;
  context.Shifts.Add(shiftitem);

}
 contex.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Then you need to delete the rows and do the savechanges()

Comment: i don't want delete rows because i use this row as foreign key in other tables

Comment: @sadeq That does not matter since schema will remain the same even if you delete and insert , or you can modify the state as modified and do the savechanges  context.Shifts.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

Comment: i use remove for delete them but it not updated
and context.Shifts has no state

Comment: give me teamviewer i will help

Comment: password is what?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question has already been answered, but for completeness sake, here is the more logical answer:

```
if (_Shifts != null)
{
    ContexManager contex = new ContexManager();
    Foreach(var shiftitem in _Shifts)
    {
        shiftitem.MyStartTime = dtStart1.Value.TimeOfDay;
        shiftitem.MyEndTime = dtEnd1.Value.TimeOfDay;
        shiftitem.MyName = txtShift1.Text;
        contex.Shifts.Attach(shiftitem);
        contex.Entry(shiftitem).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    contex.SaveChanges();
}
```

This uses System.Data.EntityState, so you will need a `using System.Data`.
It assumes you are only modifying rows and not adding any. If you want to modify only 1 specific row (e.g. the **first** row), then your original code was partially correct:

```
if (_Shifts != null)
{
    ContexManager contex = new ContexManager();
    Shift _sht = _Shifts[0];         
    _sht.MyStartTime = dtStart1.Value.TimeOfDay;
    _sht.MyEndTime = dtEnd1.Value.TimeOfDay;
    _sht.MyName = txtShift1.Text;
    contex.Shifts.Attach(_sht);
    contex.Entry(_sht).State = EntityState.Modified;
    contex.SaveChanges();
}
```